# Using Sed to capitalize the first letter of the first word in the sentences (each sentence starts with a double hyphen, -- )

Tags: text, sed, stream, editor, gnu

I would like to try to use the [Sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) command to capitalize the first letter of the first word in the sentences, in a text where all the sentences begin with a double hyphen and one space.

For example, I would like to transform this text:

```
Pluto Is A Dwarf Planet -- Chemical Elements Are Cool -- Astronomical Objects Live In Space -- The Solar System Is Our Home -- I Want To Live On Another Planet Next To My Wife.
```

Into this one:

```
Pluto is a dwarf planet -- Chemical elements are cool -- Astronomical objects live in space -- The solar system is our home -- I want to live on another planet next to my wife.
```

(There is no line break, it's a whole block of text).

Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried to read the documentation, but it is very vast and I haven't found it yet...

Comment: What did you find and try from the documentation that you read so far? Please include these as part of your question so the community can better assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/\L&/;s/^.\|-- ./\U&/g' file
```

Prepare the way by making every character lowercase.

Then translate the first character or the first character following `--` into its uppercase equivalent.

Comment: This is a great piece of code. Thank you very much! Peace!